# Where to place Fixtures that are not associated with a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

I have to test a method which takes a Hash that is associated with some content I scrap from a website.

Here is what I have tried to do in a file located in /test/fixtures/scrapped_sites.yml

```
web_sites:
  product_images: <% { 'images' => [] } %>
```

Then in my test:

```
page = Page.new
page.my_method(web_sites(:product_images))
```

But I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: scrapped_sites: DELETE FROM "scrapped_sites"
```

How/where should I create this Fixtures?

EDIT:

I have creating a file in `test/data/scrapped_data.yml` that looks like this:

```
web_sites:
  scrapped: {'images' => []}
```

But when running trying to open that file I get:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (##): did not find expected ',' or '}' while parsing a flow mapping at line 2 column 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i usually create a directory called `test/data` but its up to you. be creative!

Comment: phoet, how do I tell Rails that he should load those YAML files under test/data? What should I place in test_helper.rb? RIght now I have ```fixtures :all```

Comment: phoet, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Yaml's nested mappings](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#nested_mappings) and [Simple Inline Arrays](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#simple_inline_array)

Need to do something like (note indenting with two spaces in critical)

```
web_sites:
  scrapped:
    images: [img1.png, img2.png, img3.png]
```

Comment: I guess my question would be... What if the stored objects are not Hash? Where is the correct place to store Objects that are not associated with a Model (so, no FIxtures)